# Name for a fictional or mythological character who doesn't suffer personally, but whose family and friends all do?

Tags: terminology, myths

I feel like this must be a character archetype or mythological figure, but can't find any references to it. In my mind, it's something like Cassandra knowing the future but not being believed; this figure or myth would be a character who has basically a charmed life, but everyone they become close to has terrible luck and suffers greatly.

Comment: Hurley from "Lost"?

Comment: As currently written, this question probably falls into [an off-topic open-ended list](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1561/11259). I can see two ways to make it on-topic: either ask for the first such character (using the tag [[tag:history-of-literature]]) or ask for the name of the trope/character archetype (using [[tag:terminology]])

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about that it as an archetype or canonical myth that surely exists? I'll change the tagging. Regarding Hurley, I don't know the full story of Lost, but from what i know bad things started happening after he won the lottery using the "cursed" numbers. I think of that more as a Midas story. Maybe I'm being too picky :)

Comment: TV Tropes has a bunch of versions of this; start at [Walking Disaster Area](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WalkingDisasterArea) and follow the links.

Comment: Great reference and link, thank you! I wasn't thinking about TV Tropes at all - I assumed there *must* be a myth or classical character that embodied that idea. I'll keep searching, but this is a great reference. Thank you again.

Comment: [Cartwright Curse](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CartwrightCurse) is another TV Tropes example, kind of focusing on how love interests tend to get killed off with certain characters.

Comment: Sounds a little like Chapter One of the Biblical book of Job.

Comment: Sounds like https://tvtropes.org/Main/TheJinx... Might be called a cursed person... Given how Odysseus also is mentioned on https://tvtropes.org/Main/DoomMagnet.